# Hacer una condicion despues de un forfiles en .batch

Tags: cmd, condiciones, batch

Tengo el siguiente comando en un .batch, el cual imprime los últimos archivos modificados o creados en un directorio el día de hoy.

`forfiles /S /D 0 /C "cmd /c echo @file`

lo que quiero es hacer una condición después del mismo. 
algo tal que

`if "forfile retorna error de búsqueda"(
imprimir: "No se encontró nada") ELSE (imprimir: Si se encontró algo)`

¿Alguna idea? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final esto me sirvió

```
    if errorlevel 1 (echo No se encontró algo) ELSE ( echo Si se encontró algo)
```

Comment: Considera entregar más información para que la respuesta sea completa y clara para la comunidad